# How to stream Spotify from iPad to receiver?

Tags: ipad, hardware, music

I would like to get some answers on how I can stream music from Spotify on my iPad to my home-cinema receiver.

Exactly what hardware do I need to invest in?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [Airport Express](http://www.apple.com/airportexpress/) router or an [Apple TV](http://www.apple.com/appletv):

> Play iTunes music on your speakers. Wirelessly.
>   AirPlay takes the music from the iTunes library on your computer, iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch and sends it wirelessly to any stereo or speakers in your home. Simply connect your speakers to AirPort Express using an audio cable (sold separately). Then, using iTunes on your computer or the Music app on your iOS device, choose which speakers you want your music to play on. If you have more than one AirPort Express connected to speakers, you can play the same music from iTunes on your Mac or PC on all your speakers at the same time. Already have a Wi-Fi network in place? Use AirPort Express to add music streaming to its capabilities and create a whole-house musical experience.

[image]

Basically, play your track on Spotify, go full screen which reveals the sharing options, and from there you can pick your Airport Express which should be cabled to whatever AUX-in inputs your amp/receiver has.

The following pic' shows me doing something similar to an AppleTV (I don't own an airport express but the process is is essentially the same thing).

[image]

In fact for audio there isn't much difference between the an Apple TV and an Airport Express, and the choice of Apple TV or Airport Express is whether you want TV functions or Network functions as extra functionality over and above the audio.  The only difference for audio is that the Apple TV has an optical out port (& HDMI), and the Airport Express has a 3.5mm Analogue/Optical output,

[image: Airport Express]
[image: Apple TV]

The iPhone version of Spotify doesn't have a full screen mode, but hit the `i` for info screen and it's next to the volume slider in the bottom right - easy to miss.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! The only follow up question is about the AppleTV, sounds like that will give me more options...?

Comment: And i guess that AppleTV also make it possible to stream movies directly to the tv (and sound to the reciever)

Comment: If it's going into an AV receiver with a lot of HDMI, then I'd likely pick an AppleTV actually, on the assumption that your AV receiver can has independent speakers and isn't using your TV speakers.

Comment: The reciever i'm using now is only connected to the tv via a ps3 in the middle using hdmi from ps3 to tv, and optical from ps3 to reciever. The AppleTV could use any of the other hdmi on the tv, and use optical to the reciever (have to change the ps3 to use something other than optical though)

Comment: With that said, the hdmi from appleTV can go directly to the tv, and optical to the reciever ?

Comment: That would work :)

Comment: @JonasCannehag This is misleading. There are many other options, as Apple has made airplay open to manufacturers, and there are many different products that support airplay.  You can even use a RaspberryPI ([guide by Scott Hanselmann](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AddingAirPlayToAReceiverWithoutAnAppleTVRaspbmcAndTheRaspberryPi.aspx))

Comment: Feel free to add a useful answer rather than just downvoting one that the OP found useful.  I changed with word "need" to "can use" - something you could have done too.

Comment: iPhone version of Spotify does support Airplay. Hit The I (Info).
AirportExpress or Apple TV is the *only* hardware you need.

Comment: Thanks @HenriKoppen, I hunted for it several times and missed it - will update answer.